# Changing line height of horizontal rule

Tags: html, css

I have followed a tutorial on the internet and I have the following html template:

```css
body {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.header {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  color: #007cae;
}

.title {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 100;
  /* text-align: right;*/
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;  
}

.title span {
  color: #007cae;
}

.details {
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
  text-align: left !important;
  /*margin-left: 40%;*/
}

.hrItem {
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  /* Set the hr color */
  color: #333; /* old IE */
  background-color: #fff; /* Modern Browsers */
 }
```

```html
 <div class='wrapper'>
     <div class='header'>
       <p class='title'>Invoice #<hr class='hrItem' /> </p>
     </div>
   <div>
   <div class='details'>
       Bill to: <br/>
       Amount:  <br/>
       Date: 
   </div>
</div>
```

The problem that I am having is that between Invoice # and the horizontal rule there is a significant amount of white space that I want to remove. I tried changing the padding and the margin in the `.hrItem`,`.tittle` and `.header`, however, this made no difference. Is it possible to remove that white space or should I reconsider the method of adding the horizontal line?

Comment: Can u show live view?

Comment: hr tag usually has a lot of margin so try .hrItem{margin:0;}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to place the `<hr>` outside of your `<p>`, as having it inside is invalid HTML and actually ends up creating an empty `<p></p>`, which creates more space:

[image]

What you should have is:

```
<div class='header'>
    <p class='title'>Invoice #</p>
    <hr class='hrItem' />
</div>
```

Once you make that change, you can control the spacing between the `.hrItem` and the `.title` by changing their `margin` properties (I set both to `0`):

```css
body {
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.header {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  color: #007cae;
}
.title {
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: 100;
  /* text-align: right;*/
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;  
  margin: 0;
}
.title span {
  color: #007cae;
}
.details {
  padding: 10px 20px 0px 20px;
  text-align: left !important;
  /*margin-left: 40%;*/
}
.hrItem {
  border: none;
  height: 1px;
  /* Set the hr color */
  color: #333; /* old IE */
  background-color: #fff; /* Modern Browsers */
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='header'>
    <p class='title'>Invoice #</p>
    <hr class='hrItem' /> 
  </div>
         
  <div class='details'>
    Bill to: <br/>
    Amount:  <br/>
    Date: 
  </div>
</div>
```